# How do I find $\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{2z-i}{z+2i}\right)\text{?}$

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I find:

$$\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{2z-i}{z+2i}\right)\text{?}\quad\quad z\in\Bbb C$$

---

Do I turn it into an $x+iy$ form and use the Cauchy-Riemann equations?

---

I couldn't get it into such a form, so I tried the Quotitent rule, treating $z$ as if it were real, so pretty much just calculus - I got the answer slightly wrong(probably a little error somewhere), but it took so many steps that I doubt this is the correct method.

Comment: The quotient rule works perfectly and is very very simple. Actually, all the usual derivation rules hold ($+,-,\times,\div,f^{-1}(z),g(f(z)),z^n,e^z\cdots$). Just take care in case of non holomorphic terms, like $|z|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the numerator, we have
$$ 2z-i=2x+2yi-i=2x+(2y-1)i $$
So now
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}[2x] =\frac{\partial}{\partial y}[2y-1]= 2 $$
And
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}[2y-1] =-\frac{\partial}{\partial y}[2x]= 0$$
Therefore 
$$ 2z-i\Rightarrow \mbox{is analytic} $$
For the denominator, we have
$$ z+2i=x+yi +2i=x+(y+2)i $$
So now
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}[x] =\frac{\partial}{\partial y}[y+2]= 1$$
And
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}[y+2] =-\frac{\partial}{\partial y}[x]= 0$$
Therefore 
$$ z+2i\Rightarrow \mbox{is analytic} $$
Since $2z-i$ and $z+2i$ are both analytic, then $$\frac{2z-i}{z+2i}\Rightarrow \mbox{is analytic} $$
Hence
$$\frac{d}{dz}\left[\frac{2z-i}{z+2i}\right]$$ $$=\frac{(z+2i)\frac{d}{dz}[2z-i]-(2z-i)\frac{d}{dz}[z+2i]}{(z+2i)^2}$$
$$=\frac{2z+4i-2z+i}{(z+2i)^2} =\frac{5i}{(z+2i)^2} $$

Comment: Omg I am so sorry I mistyped the question, I don't know what to do now. It was meant to be $\frac{d}{dz}$

Comment: @SkiesBurn, you can simply just edit your question.

Comment: Just quotient ruled it? Would it be expected to use Cauchy-Riemann first to ensure it is analytic?

Comment: @SkiesBurn, Please see my edit.

Comment: None of this is required to solve the question as it is now.

Comment: @Did, what would've been a better approach? I was asked by the OP to show that the function is indeed analytic, prior to arriving at the result.

Comment: Simply to note that this is a rational function $Q(z)$ of $z$ hence one can differentiate $Q$ directly without decomposing it into its real and imaginary parts. And $Q(X)=(2X-i)/(X+2i)=2-5i/(X+2i)$ hence $Q'(X)=-(-5i)/(X+2i)^2=5i/(X+2i)^2$ hence the desired derivative is $5i/(z+2i)^2$ for every $z\ne-2i$.